# Keeping an array of users in sync with their mentions in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create an array of users[id,name]

```
31, Bob Smith
22, Rac Meda
301, Bill burns
```

With this array I need to be able to:

1. Add an item to the array
2. Given a name, determine if the name is in the array
3. Given a textarea with the 3 names, when a user modifies the text area validate that the 3 names are still in the textarea. If not, remove the name from the array.

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: i have cMentions = [], and then I do cMentions.push([id,name]) but they keep adding, id isn't unique? How can I push with ID being the key?

Comment: I know how to do without jquery, it is indispensable?

Comment: It doesn't have to be w jQuery, pure JS is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the `<textarea>` you can split the input's value at the end of each line, then loop through each line and split it by `', '` (a comma and a space).

HTML

```
<textarea>31, Bob Smith
22, Rac Meda
301, Bill burns</textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
//declare an object so we can make an associative array
var myObj = {};

//bind an event handler to the change event for the textarea
$('textarea').bind('change', function () {

    //separate all the lines in the textarea
    var lines = this.value.split("\n"),
        tmp   = '';

    //iterate through each line
    for (a in lines) {

        //split the line at its comma
        tmp = lines[a].split(', ');

        //add the key->value pair to our object
        myObj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }

    //check to see if Bob smith is in the array of users, if so then alert
    if ($.inArray('Bob Smith', myObj)) {
        alert('Bob\'s In');
    }
}).trigger('change');//this runs the event handler on load
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/Xq2qc/1/

NOTE: This code does not handle complex user interactions where the user may not use the exact syntax when adding/removing users from the textbox; I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Comment: Why separate the lines in the textarea?

Comment: #1. `myObj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];` is the code that adds items to the associative array. `tmp[0]` is the key (or ID) and `tmp[1]` is the value (name).

Comment: #2. `if ($.inArray('Bob Smith', myObj)){...}` is the code that checks for a user in the array. If you want to check for an ID, use this to check for the existence of a key: `if (<id_value> in myObj) {...}`.

Comment: I used the lines to separate users because its a natural break-point however you can use whatever syntax you want.

Comment: For creating an array, I shouldn't use push? In your example myObj[tmp[0]],,, myObj is [], what is tmp?

Comment: I tried it with cMentions[id[0]] = name[1]; where id and name are strings and the created undefined...

Comment: the `tmp` variable was just used to split each line in the textbox at it's comma, that way you can programmatically store the ID and the name of a user.